# If $F$ satisfies conditions for a c.d.f., then it is a c.d.f. for some random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, cumulative-distribution-functions

Larry Wasserman , in his *All of Statistics*, states that for any cdf $F$ :

- $F$ is non-decreasing
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} F = 0 \ \ \text{and} \ \ \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} F = 1$
- $F$ is right continuous

He then writes that proving that if $F$ satisfies these conditions, then it is a cdf for some random variable, requires "some deep tools in analysis."

Does anyone know where I can find a proof of this exact statement, and if not, how it would be proved?

Thanks.

Comment: The key ingredient is the [Carathéodory extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carathéodory's_extension_theorem). One defines $\mu([a,b))=F(b)-F(a)$ and argues that this extends to a measure on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$, whose cdf will, by definition, then be $F$.

Comment: Under stronger hypotheses ($F$ continuous and strictly increasing), you might be interested to think about a proof from scratch (consider $F^{-1}(x)$ where $x$ is drawn uniformly from $(0,1)$).